# How to add red lines under <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have problem, with which html tag I can make these lines ?
The width of long line is 135px, the width short line is 75px.

```css
.vip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

small {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8E98A7;
}

.line-break {
  width: 100%;
}

.red-line {
  width: 135px;
  background-color: #FF193F;
}

.red-line-short {
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #E62E4C;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vip">
    <small>CHECK SOME VIP CONTENT</small>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <p>VIP объявления</p>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <!-- Long line should be here -->
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <!-- Short line should be here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[the final result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hhp0.png)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You can use <hr>, border-bottom, or just insert a PNG image.

Comment: Just use 2 divs with a small height, respective widths and red background.

Comment: @IvanKuckir Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a height to the class, otherwise it is not visible.

```
.line-break {
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` CSS styling on a paragraph to have red line below paragraph

```css
.vip {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
    
small {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8E98A7;
}

.line-break {
    width: 100%;
}

.red-line {
    width: 135px;
    background-color: #FF193F;
}

.red-line-short {
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #E62E4C;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
            <div class="vip">
                <small>CHECK SOME VIP CONTENT</small>
                <div class="line-break"></div>
                <p>VIP объявления</p>
                <div class="line-break"></div>
               <!-- Long line should be here -->
                <div class="line-break"></div>
               <!-- Short line should be here -->
            </div>
        </div>
```